# Syntax Error? Code runs fine without lines 16-17, but errors out otherwise

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am trying to import data into a DynamoDB table using a CSV file, and the connections and everything work correctly, however, I continuously get a syntax error on lines 16-17. In the CSV file, the objects are listed exactly like the variable in the code. (I have more than 2 columns, and about 415 rows, so this is frustrating)

I have tried deleting extra rows to limit it to 1, and it still errors out on 'name':row.split(',')[0] .

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
def csv_reader(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

    rows = obj['Body'].read().split('\n')
    table = dynamodb.Table('ServiceOfferings')

    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for row in rows:
            batch.put_item(Item={
                'name':row.split(',')[0],
                'business_criticality':row.split(',')[1]
            })



An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the BatchWriteItem 
operation: The provided key element does not match the schema: 
ClientError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 17, in csv_reader
'business_criticality':row.split(',')[1]
File "/var/runtime/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 101, in put_item
self._add_request_and_process({'PutRequest': {'Item': Item}})
File "/var/runtime/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 110, in 
_add_request_and_process
self._flush_if_needed()
File "/var/runtime/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 131, in 
_flush_if_needed
self._flush()
File "/var/runtime/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 137, in _flush
RequestItems={self._table_name: items_to_send})
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the 
BatchWriteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the 
schema
```

Result should apply the information to the DynamoDB table, with the 5 or so columns, and 415 rows.

Comment: A missing comma in the data should not lead to a syntax error.

Comment: Missing comma? Why would it throw an error then

Comment: What does exactly your error states?

Comment: Error has been added to code above.

Comment: First, check a few things, is your table name correct? Are you passing all the values like you are not missing on any mandatory ids (primary key) in put_item and what is the data type of business_criticality is it in numbers(0,1,2) or string(easy,hard)?

Comment: dynamodb table is "ServiceOfferings" i updated the code above to fix that, but i still get an error. The error has now changed to the updated code above.

Comment: It’s not a syntax error in your code, what is happening is that the data doesn’t match your expection. Have you tried simply printing the results of the split on each row - does that work?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Right, so focus on that - the `rows` data doesn’t have the shape you expect

Comment: Your table schema doesn't match the input you are providing. Check each and every input column name and data type. Check the schema again that will do the job. It isn't syntax error.

Comment: Would partition key on the dynamodb affect this? i have it set to id (number).

Comment: instead of row should i put column? Each row is different, but the columns are definitely correct in the naming schema.

Comment: Looks like it is complaining about `business_criticality` not passing validation  - check that business_criticality is in fact in schema or perhaps the data from `row.split(',')[1]` isn't valid for your definition of business_criticality.